# Unsupported Operand *

Tags: rospy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I'm using Indigo on a RPi,

I'm running a code and am getting the error

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/catkin_ws/src/servo $ rosrun servo pigpio_listner.py
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1423671413.743414] bad callback: <function set at 0x1f12670>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 702, in _invoke_callback
    cb(msg)
  File "/home/pi/catkin_ws/src/servo/pigpio_listner.py", line 13, in set
    pulswidth=1000+angle*5.5556
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Float32' and 'float'

Unhandled exception in thread started by 
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

I'm not sure what this means, doesn't * mean multiply? Can't you multiply floats?
I'll include the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import Float32
import time
import pigpio

servos = 4 #GPIO number

pi=pigpio.pi()


def set(angle):
        pulswidth=1000+angle*5.5556
        pi.set_servo_pulsewidth(servos, pulswidth)

def listener():
        rospy.init_node('servo', anonymous=True)

        rospy.Subscriber("angle", Float32, set)

        rospy.spin

if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
                listener()


# switch all servos off
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
                pigpio.set_servo_pulsewidth(servos, 0);
                pigpio.stop()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202925/unsupported-operand-*/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2015-02-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`Float32` is not a float, it's a type that has a `.data` member, which is a float.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2015-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on 2015-02-13**:
Okay, how do I address this problem. Do I change the subscriber to Float32.data, or to float?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2015-02-16**:
Leave the subscriber as it is, you are subscribing to a `Float32` message, just change the function to access `angle.data` instead. It might help to think of `std_msgs/Float32` as a `std_msgs/Float32DataMessage`.

**Comment by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on 2015-02-16**:
Thanks, that helped. I'm getting a new error now, so I'm posting a new question for that.